# How to disable notification sounds from other logged in users on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, notifications

There are two users on my M1 Mac Mini. Fast user switching is enabled. The other user is logged in and has notifications for Gmail enabled though Firefox. Everytime they receive a chat message, I hear a notification sound while actively using my account. It's infuriating and seemingly not the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> **It's seemingly not the intended behavior.**

Fast User Switching keeps all users' processes running in the background. Apps like browsers and Mail can 'ping' the user when they are in the background. If you want to stop their processes, then those accounts should log out.

Comment: Til. Still seems bizarre to me. But simple solution.